# Receiver-initiated file sharing

Tags: web-apps, sharing, data-transfer

I don't have an iPhone, and recently I was in a situation where somebody wanted to airdrop a file to me, but my phone couldn't accept it. I had to tediously explain why this couldn't work, and the transfer took a very long time. This got me thinking about general purpose file sharing, and I realized that I needed a reliable way for someone to give me a file, with no requirements on their end except an Internet connection and a browser. Essentially, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a web service that would allow me to do something similar to the following:

- Send somebody a link.
- That person then follows it, and the page allows them to upload a file to my account, and perhaps shows a message about what file I'm expecting
- I get an email/notification/alert to accept or decline, and the file is then given to me by a share link, download, or is ideally put directly into a folder of my OneDrive, Google Drive, or Dropbox.

My main motivation is that a disturbingly large number of people don't know how to upload and share a file, so I would like to make the process of sharing a file with me as quick and painless as possible.

Comment: A hosted or self-hosted Web app?

Comment: Either one will work. I was hoping this kind of thing already existed, but I might just have to just make my own.

Comment: Why can't the sender use OneDrive, Google Drive, or Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

[send.firefox.com](https://send.firefox.com/) is the most simple option for files under 1GB.

You could use a free service like Google Drive, but you are right it could be more simple.

[Uploading to Someone Else's Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30285/uploading-to-someone-elses-google-drive)

You could run your own web server with a simple 20 line upload page, but upload is slow on some connections.

You could use your Android phone as a web server but that's only useful if you are on the same WiFi.

Emailing someone a link to your personal web server upload page is the best solution most of the time, and it optionally gives you an excuse to learn about SBCs, Linux, PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The program [woof](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/woof.html) does something like this, although I've only used it on my desktop. On Android, you could probably run that in Termux or a similar app.

You run `woof -U` in a terminal and it'll give you a URL someone can type in their browser to get an upload page.

Keep in mind, the URL is usually a private IP address, so it's not memorable and will require you to be on the same Wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

Nextcloud has this feature, just take a look at their [documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13/admin_manual/configuration_files/file_sharing_configuration.html), `Allow public uploads` is what you want.